# Return Multiple Values in Meteor for Handlebars Template

Tags: javascript, meteor

How do I do this in Meteor?

```
Template.foo.bar = function() {


someVar = return value of some other function
return SomeCollection and someVar;

}
```

-------Template----

```
{{#each someCollection}}
{{someVar}} {{someCollectionField}}
{{/each}}
```

in regular javascript I could just use an array to return multiple values how does it work in Meteor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return a js object and use handlebars to go through it

Client js

```
Template.foo.bar = function() {
    someVar = getmyotherfunction();
    return {
            SomeCollection: SomeCollection.find({...}),
            someVar: someVar
           };

}
```

Client html

```
<template name="foo">
    {{#each bar.SomeCollection}}
        {{bar.someVar}} 
        {{someCollectionField}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

You can access a bar value inside the handlebars each loop and just use `.` to get inside objects. Arrays also work, use `.0` to get the first item in the array, 0 being the index.